# YII2 PDO Error with MSSQL 2017 on Docker?

Tags: yii2, php-7.2, mamp-pro, sql-server-2017-express

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'auth_item'.
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM [auth_item] WHERE [name]='admin'
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S02
    [1] => 208
    [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'auth_item'.
)
↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'auth_item'.
```

**configuration:**
OS X, MAMP Pro 5.7 (php 7.4.2), MSSQL 2017 on Docker-Stack

Installed via https://noobis.de/macos-php73-mssql-setup/

Anybody got any ideas for me?

Comment: Have you run RBAC migrations? I mean [this](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#using-db-manager).

Comment: Yes I use the RBAC migrations.

Comment: So have you checked if there are in fact these tables in your database?